# Quais as práticas corretas para manipular eventos em PHP?

Tags: php, design-pattern, eventos, observer-pattern

Criei algumas classes e uma interface para manipular eventos para uma pequena aplicação MVC. Meu intuito é implementar o padrão Observer, mas não sei se está de acordo, já que ainda me confundo com ele em PHP. No código a seguir, eu o fiz da forma correta, ou isso pode vir a causar algum problema de manutenção no futuro?

```php
<?php
# Interface do listener 
interface ActionListener {
    public function actionPerformed(ActionEvent $e);
}

# O evento
class ActionEvent {

    private $eventSource;
    private $id;
    private $command;
    private $time;

    public function __construct($eventSource, $id, $command = '') {
        $this->eventSource = $eventSource;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->command = $command;
        $this->time = time();
    }

    public function getEventSource() {
        return $this->eventSource;
    }

    public function getID() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCommand() {
        return $this->command;
    }

    public function getTime() {
        return $this->time;
    }
}

# Uma fonte de eventos.
class EventSource {

    private $listeners = [];

    public function notify($id, $command = '') {
        $event = new ActionEvent($this, $id, $command);
        foreach ($this->listeners as $actual) {
            $actual->actionPerformed($event);
        }
    }

    public function addActionListener(ActionListener $object) {
        $this->listeners[] = $object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você não foi claro em seu questionamento. Você precisa dizer exatamente o que você precisa. Um site de Q&A não é adequado para pedir opiniões. A plataforma funciona bem para perguntas objetivas. Explicitamente não se deve pedir opiniões e sim soluções que possam ser respondidas de forma relativamente curta. Eu consigo ver mais de um motivo para fechar esta questão do jeito que ela está formulada. Vou aguardar se você consegue deixá-la objetiva. Me parece uma questão de Code Review. Veja em inglês formas de pedir CR: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: É uma boa questão, já reformulada. É importante para comunidade interessada ter um feedback sobre esse tema.

Comment: Não questiono o conteúdo. Uma simples mudança já melhorou bem a forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Design Pattern Observer (também conhecido como Publish-Subscribe) na verdade é uma espécie de relacionamento um-para-muitos entre objetos, ou seja, quando um objeto muda seu estado, os objetos **dependentes** são atualizados.

Programação orientada a eventos é de certa forma um conceito um pouco mais abstrato, e pode ser implementado de diversas formas.

Geralmente, tecnologias baseadas em eventos tendem a serem assíncronas, temos como exemplo o [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/).

Mas, supondo que a pergunta seja sobre a implantação do Design Pattern Observer, não existe implementação oficial de nenhum padrão, porêm [esse artigo](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-the-observer-pattern/) pode ser um bom ponto de partida.

Normalmente, para a implementação desse padrão, temos as classes [SplObserver](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobserver.php) e [SplSubject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splsubject.php) da Biblioteca padrão do PHP (SPL) que são **interfaces** para que você implemente o padrão.

Recomendo olhar tais interfaces e comparar com sua implementação do padrão, e se possível, adequar suas classes para que implementem tais interfaces.

[Nesse Artigo em Português](http://www.revistaphp.com.br/artigo.php?id=209), você pode encontrar um exemplo de implementação do padrão usando as interfaces da SPL.